# How can I stop foot-prints showing in Vitrified paving?

Tags: driveway, stone, pavers

We've had some [vitrified paving](http://www.stonemarket.co.uk/product-fortuna-vitrified-paving) laid at the front of the house.  We're noticing that footprints are very visible (if someone comes to the door, we can see the exact route they took).

Is there a way to make this less visible, like 'sealing' them or something?

Comment: The site you linked to says the tiles "absorb[s] little or no moisture".  What do you mean the footprints are visible?  Because of dirt or water or what?

Comment: Dirt and dust mainly.  Before the path bit is gravel.